# cakePHP - Download File through Controller

Tags: php, file, cakephp, download

I'm using the cakePHP framework for my website and I would like to create an action which, rather than sending HTML, instead echos the contents of a file. It can't be stored in a public directory, as the data is confidential.

Before using the framework, I accomplished this by rewriting /downloads/KEY/FILE to file.php?key=KEY&file=FILE

However, I can't find any clear way to do this using cakePHP. Essentially, I'd like a way to either:

1. When a user accesses a controller action from its URL a .jar file is sent, not a webpage.
2. A URL is redirected to a PHP file which separately connects to a database and serves the file.

Note that cakePHP is at my domain root. Also, as I'm using SSL for the transfer and I do not ow n a wildcard certificate, I cannot use a subdomain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use Media view: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1094/Media-Views